# How do I pass a struct field as a function output in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, struct, output

I have a function that uses structs. I would like to pass one of the fields of a struct as an output from the function. Here's an example of what I'd *like* to do:

```
function MyStructure.myField = my_function(input)
MyStructure.myField = input * 3;
```

However, MATLAB doesn't allow the dot (.) notation in function outputs. I could of course work around the situation quite simply by doing this:

```
function myOutput = my_function(input)
MyStructure.myField = input * 3;
myOutput = MyStructure.myField;
```

A simple workaround, but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution..?

Comment: I don't see why it matters that it's a struct field. It seems that the struct is entirely contained in your function, so why would you want to return it in a special way? Your workaround seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: The code above is an illustrative example. In my real code I have multiple fields in my struct and would like to return just one field without having to add extra lines to my code.

Comment: Your workaround is the only way to do that, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Your is THE solution, not a workaround. You have not provided enough info to determine why you would need what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is ignore the struct in the function and only use it when the function is called. For example:

```
function output = my_function(input)
% manipulate...
output = 3*input;
```

When you call the function, you use the struct:

```
myStruct.myField = my_function(input)
```